# Why does Tony Stark say this sentence about foul language?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Iron Man shoots at the fort and hits an energy shield, ending up saying

> Shit!

and Captain America warns him with

> Language!

A couple of minutes later, Iron Man says:

> Wait a second. No-one else is gonna deal with the fact that Cap just said "Language"?

Why does he do that? Am I missing something? As far I can hear, nobody swears.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't mention that Captain America and Iron Man have some friction between them.

Comment: And then there's the follow-up line, when Cap says he "slipped", which was historically a common excuse given when somebody violated a rule about using such language.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's Tony having a little fun at Cap's expense.  Captain America is from a much earlier period where swearing was less socially acceptable than it is today, and by reflex he tells Tony off.

He's still getting used to the social norms of the 21st century.

Tony's mocking him for being so outdated, which is a bit of a theme with the two of them - he refers to Steve as a "Cap-sicle" in the first Avengers movie, which is to do with Steve being frozen like a popsicle ice lolly, while asking about Pilates and telling him he might have missed a few things.

Tony's also asking if nobody else is essentially going to call out/mock Cap on his somewhat old time values.

Comment: And not just his values of not swearing, but him telling another adult how to speak like he was a child.

Comment: While its true that he was from an earlier time, I think any army vet from WWII (sadly less and less around these days) will tell you folks swore every bit as much in that environment as today, if not more. I think its more just part of his "boy scout" personality.

Comment: @T.E.D. They swore heavily amongst themselves, but probably avoided it in public, especially anywhere with women present.

Comment: Although Cap seems so much of a boy scout that I suspect he didn't even swear with his earlier comrades.

Comment: @Barmar - Thing is, they were literally in combat when the "Language." statement was made. One gets the impression he did it absent-mindedly, like it was the same thing he would have said in a similar situation leading a team in WWII, and just forgot himself for a moment.

Comment: @T.E.D. Haven't seen the movie yet (yes, if you heard a rumor that there's someone on the planet who hasn't, that's me), but there are women in the Avengers, aren't there? We can't disturb their delicate senses, even if they have super powers.

Comment: @Barmar There is absolutely no evidence that the presence of one female on his team (who notably does *not* have any powers) had anything to do with it.

Comment: @jpmc26 That seems likely. I was just trying to suggest a possibility to T.E.D., who thinks that an army vet would not find cursing objectionable.

Comment: @Barmar He didn't say a vet wouldn't find it objectionable. He said that people cursed a lot in combat situations, so it's unlikely Cap wouldn't have encountered it before. T.E.D.'s point is that Cap finding it objectionable mid-combat is *weird*, even by the standards of WWII soldiers, and as such is more likely his personality than it is a product of his time period.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yeah. I suspect trying to find an in-universe explanation requires some contortions. It was really done by the writers just as a humorous way to illustrate a difference between Stark and Rogers.

Comment: @T.E.D. we see in the battle of Wakanda in *Infinity Wars* that Steve's gentle manners come first when he answers to "I am Groot" by introducing himself.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does he do that? Am I missing something? As far I can hear, nobody swears

To answer your question directly; "shit" is considered to be "swearing" or a "swear word".  It can still fall into that category in today's society, but its generally not seen as extreme as it was back in Steve Rodger's days.  It was definitively a swear word as recently as the 90's, so Rodgers isn't that far off anyhow.

Comment: In the US it isn't even allowed on network TV channels. So in that sense it is still "officially" a swear word.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think that was relaxed around the turn of the millennium to be allowed after some time like 9:00 or 10:00pm. South Park had an entire episode inspired by the rules change.

Comment: @ToddWilcox South Park is on cable TV, not network. But I don’t know if that relaxed rule extends to network TV.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah good point. Before that time, it also wasn’t allowed on basic cable and now it is. So there was a change, it just didn’t affect network TV. Actually I think you can swear on network TV but you’ll be fined for it. So if a network really wants it in, they can just pay the fine.